# How to use Spring Boot CAS authentication with React frontend

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cas

My application has an API server (Spring Boot) and a client-facing server (React), the React server will make API requests on behalf of an authenticated user. For authentication, I use a CAS server provided by a third-party.

I used the [Java Apereo CAS Client](https://github.com/apereo/java-cas-client#spring-boot-autoconfiguration) (version 3.6.2), and add the following API endpoints for the React app to call:

```java
@RestController
public class CASController {

    @Value("${cas.server-url-prefix}")
    private String CASUrl;

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String getCASUserId(HttpServletRequest request){
        return request.getRemoteUser();

    }

    @GetMapping("/logout")
    public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if(session != null || !request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()) {
            String id = session.getId();
            session.invalidate();
            log.info("JSESSIONID: " + id + " is valid: " + request.isRequestedSessionIdValid());
        }
        try{
            response.sendRedirect(CASUrl + "/logout");
        }
        catch (IOException | IllegalStateException e){
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

The above endpoints work if the Spring Boot app interacts with the client directly but it doesn't, it accepts requests from the React server. When the React app tries to call: `localhost:8080/login`, it failed because of the redirection.

A way to work around this is to call the CAS server from the React app, then send the required info (service URL & ticket issued by the CAS server) to the backend, and let the backend make the ticket validation call, if the ticket validation success, then the user is authenticated and a session id is sent back to the React app for subsequent requests.

My questions are:

- Does the workaround even make sense? Authentification is split between the frontend (get a ticket from CAS server) and the backend (validate the issued ticket with CAS server and issue session). If it doesn't, what is a better solution?
- For the workaround, I think I will need to use Spring Security for this instead of [Java Apereo CAS Client](https://github.com/apereo/java-cas-client#spring-boot-autoconfiguration)? If that's the case, how do I do it?
  I tried something like this:

Ticket validation endpoint:

```java
@GetMapping("/login")
    public String getCASUserId(@RequestParam @NotBlank String URL,
                               @RequestParam @NotBlank String ticket,
                               HttpServletRequest request){
        
        // make the call the the CAS server for ticket validation
        String userId = userService.getUserId(url, ticket);

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("userId", userId);

        return userId;

    }
```

The ticket is validated, session issued but no endpoint is actually protected since neither spring-security nor Java Apereo CAS Client is enabled.

Comment: You could use something like redis cloud to store the session token? If your service provides a database to store tokens though, just use that.

Comment: @wjpayne83 I have to use the third-party CAS server for authentication, it's a requirement. I'm not sure how the location where I store the session is relevant in this case?

Comment: I get that now, you updated the question after I asked. Sorry for the confusion! Carry on and good luck.